# Addressing jQuery Google Maps object without instance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, kml, jquery-widgets

I'm trying to add a KML layer to an existing google maps object without having control over the object instance (and initializing).

So far I figured out that the object is at (DOM):
window.google.maps...
(okay, this is just the constructor, not the rendered Map object itself)

This is what i want to add to the existing(?) instance of the google.maps.Map object:

```
var kmlUrl = 'http://.../polygon-simple.kml';

var kmlOptions = {
  suppressInfoWindows: false,
  preserveViewport: true
};

var kmlLayer = new window.google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);
```

The page including the Map object is delivered by a hosting company and uses it's own jQuery widget to generate the object. I can add my javascript inside the html-body (where the "server-side" creation of the map also takes place).

Since I can't change the sources of the used JS-files and CMS-added JS, I need to address the existing object and do something like:

```
kmlLayer.set(obj.Map);
```

to apply my additions and update the Map object. But it doesn't work, obviously.

I firebug'd the whole website and tried to find the Map instance, generated by the jQuery widget - nothing. I traversed through every object on the site - nothing.

Writing the code for the Google Map completely on my own is no option, because I need to keep it configurable in the back-end for non-devs.

I guess the problem moves towards a jQuery widget issue... Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you creating the "existing google maps object"?  The window.google.maps... is the Google Maps Javascript API code.

Comment: what i found: `self.map = new window.google.maps.Map(self.container[0], ...` I guess, I do some more debugging to get the scope of "self" Leads this into the right direction? The code is minified and very hard to read...

Comment: Okay, trying to get the scope was a bad idea. I'm totally lost in my kind of "debugging" using Firebug and DOM Inspector. A mixture of the hoster's code, jQuery and all the Google API stuff is way to heavy for my little JS-knowledge. Any ideas? Maybe some other useful in-browser tools?

Comment: @geocodezip Okay, finally I ended up using your geoxml3 lib and do the whole KML processing "on my own" (with geoxml3). A little hint would have been nice geocodezip ;-)

Answer (score 0):

window.google.maps.Map is not the map object, it is the constructor of said object. The object itself is in another castle (variable).

```
obj instanceof google.maps.Map
```

should return true if the object is a googlemaps Map object. If you really can't find the variable you can write a loop that goes through all objects on your page recursively to find the object that returns true to this line.

As a side note in the chrome debugger the Map object appears like this:
[image: map]

It says that the map type is "em" which is rather odd, this is because the GoogleMaps library is minified

Comment: I already traversed through every object on the site but none of them seems to be a "derived" copy from the window.google.maps.Map constructor. I guess it should look like a copy as the Map constructor is the prototype for the inherited object, isn't it?

Comment: Okay, once again I traversed through every object on the site. None is matching :( I did more research and found out, that the Map object is generated through a jQuery widget written by the hoster. The scope of `self` is inside the object-creation of the jQuery widget. I even get access to the widget object through jQuery addressing `$( ":data( 'ui-externalcontentUiMaps' )" )`. But I'm still not able to get to the Map object itself. [Source of the hoster's jQ widget](http://helpcenter.epages.com/Doc/ver_6_17_3/epages/jQuery/source/maps.html)

Comment: @NiGe In the plugin code you can see this line at the start: 'var self = this' and the map object is stored in 'self.map'. So if you can get the reference to this plugin generate object object you can just add '.map' to it to get the googlemaps reference

Comment: Okay, I ended up doing the whole map on my own (with geoxml3).